# How do you test for permissions?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there a way to simulate whether permission are granted or denied to use services like location on the Windows Phone 7? I want to get the users current location, but I can't seem to find away to make the phone show me the permissions dialog so that I can deny access to it for testing? Anyone else have these kinds of issues? I'm finding it rather hard to really test this stuff without having the actual hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to check for permissions. When app is certified, AppHub scans application for code requiring permissions and updates WMAppManifest.xml.
When user installs your app, he agrees on all permissions you need. So if it's launched, then you got all you need.

Answer (score 2):

I can't seem to find any built-in support to check if the user will allow the location & push notification services to be used within an application.

I would expect a location-aware Windows Phone 7 app to present a dialog box to the user informing that location services will be used within the app. The dialog box has a "Allow" and a "Deny" option. Based on the selection of the user, the app may or may not use the location of the user. I have used [Shawn Wildermuth's Child Window](http://wildermuth.com/2010/08/17/Using_ChildWindow_in_Windows_Phone_7_Projects) to evaluate the user's choice and use their decision in their application accordingly.

HTH,
indyfromoz

Comment: I think where the disconnect is that it's completely up to the app designer to properly implement the "allow/deny" scenario and that the device itself doesn't implement it. I think I was expecting the device to pop a dialog not build one myself. Similar to how the BlackBerry works.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I didn't find any developer guidance on this and ended up looking at what others are doing. It is unfortunate that we do not have any guidance here.

Comment: There's some information in the app cert reqts, section 2.10.4 to 2.10.8